# Add a 'Count' Column in a DataGridView for Grouped Values

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint, datagridview

I'm populating a DataGridView from a SharePoint List which works fine.

I need a new column in the DataGridView that displays the count of each grouped list item.

So far I have:

```
if (collListItem.Count != 0)
{
    var dtCoaching = new DataTable();

    dtCoaching.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
       new DataColumn("Call Type"),  new DataColumn("Count")
    });

    foreach (var oListItem in collListItem)
    {
        dtCoaching.Rows.Add(oListItem["Call_x0020_Type"]);
    }

    dtCoaching = dtCoaching.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["Call Type"]})
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["Call Type"]).First())
    .CopyToDataTable();

    if (dataGridViewCallType!= null)
    {
        dataGridViewCallType.DataSource = dtCoaching;
    }                   
}
```

I've seen plenty of solutions that output to Console, which is great, but I need the DataTable to bind to the DataGridView, not output to console.

This is the output so far:

[Click for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07vPY.png)

I just need the count column to work!

Thanks

Davie

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, need to clone the DataTable and build a new one with the Count column.

```
            if (collListItem.Count != 0)
            {
                var dtCoaching = new DataTable();

                dtCoaching.Columns.AddRange(new[]
                {
                    new DataColumn("Call Type"),  new DataColumn("Count")
                });

                foreach (var oListItem in collListItem)
                {
                    dtCoaching.Rows.Add(oListItem["Call_x0020_Type"]);
                }

                var result = from row in dtCoaching.AsEnumerable()
                             group row by row.Field<string>("Call Type") into grp
                             select new
                             {
                                 CallType = grp.Key,
                                 CallCount = grp.Count()
                             };

                DataTable dtCoachingClone = new DataTable();
                dtCoachingClone = dtCoaching.Clone();

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dtCoachingClone.NewRow();
                    newRow["Call Type"] = item.CallType;
                    newRow["Count"] = item.CallCount;
                    dtCoachingClone.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }

                if (dataGridViewCallType != null)
                {
                    dataGridViewCallType.DataSource = dtCoachingClone;
                }

                return;
            }
```